# C++ - Struct addition via streams, what's wrong with this code?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, stream

I am practicing streams in C++ because I've got a midterm coming up in school. I am trying to write a small program that adds items to a list of Nodes (structs). I've got the following code, and am getting a clear error, but don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node {  
    string name;
    Node *next;
};

void foo(istream &in, ostream &out, Node *list) {
    string nom;
    in >> nom;                     //Assigns value to nom via cin
    Node *temp = list;

    while (temp->next != NULL) {   //Loops through list to find null pointer
        temp = temp->next;            //to add new Node to
    }

    Node item;                     //Creates new Node with a NULL next
    item.name = nom;
    item.next = NULL;
    temp->next = item;             //Adds item to the list
    out << nom;                    //Outputs that it's been added
    cout << " added" << endl;
}

int main() {
    Node one;
    one.next = NULL;  
    foo(cin, cout, &one);
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Cannot convert 'Node' to 'Node*' in assignment (Line 22)
```

Comment: The error message is very clear, look at the type of item vs the type of Node::next

Comment: The error says it all. Your `temp->next` is a pointer to `Node`, but you are trying to assign it to the object of `Node`. You might be tempted to assign it to the address of `item`, but that would not be right too - it's a local variable, and you shouldn't save it's address in something which will outlive it.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the type mismatch (`Node` and `Node*` are not the same), you did not allocate `item` dynamically, and it's going to be destroyed when `foo` finishes. Assigning `&item` would leave you with invalid `temp->next`.

In code:

```
Node *item = new Node;
item->name = nom;
item->next = nullptr; // I can't write NULL
temp->next = item;
```

condensed into one statement:

```
temp->next = new Node{nom, nullptr};
```